# How to test if PowerShell console has been executed with -noexit switch?

Tags: powershell

A PowerShell console can be executed with `-noexit`switch to prevent auto-closing after script execution.

But how to know inside a script if the console will be closed automatically or not  ?
I didn't find anything in `$host` or `$MyInvocation`.

**why the question**

I don't want to change globally the noexit behavior.
I do a pause a the end of some script, I would like to call pause only if necessary, because it's annoying to have to press enter when we are already inside an opened console that will not exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using PowerShell WMI classes

You can use the WMI class `Win32_Process` to show the full command processes were started using. E.g. to view how `powershell.exe` was started, you can run

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'powershell.exe'" | Select-Object CommandLine
```

In my case it tells me

```
CommandLine
-----------
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -noexit
```

To get the command line for the current PowerShell prompt, then simply run

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "handle = $pid" | Select-Object CommandLine
```

#### Using System.Enviroment

Or you can do it even simpler, as pointed out by Joroen Mostert in the comments below. Just run

```
[System.Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()
```

Comment: Identifying your *own* PowerShell process is easy -- it's the one with a PID of `$PID`. Getting your own *command line* is easier than that -- just use `[System.Environment]::CommandLine`. But figuring out if `-noexit` is in there is *even easier than that*, using `[System.Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()` (and now I've almost written an answer. :-))

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will mark it as accepted, but in fact my question is wrong, because when you open the powershell default console, there is no `noexit` switch, it's just a shortcut to powershell.exe. But with `[System.Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()`, I can know how the script is executed and if I have to do the pause or not.